# missing values when converting Django rest framework data to javascript array

Tags: javascript, ajax, django-rest-framework

I am trying to extract some data which i have placed at my API end point through AJAX. 
However , it seems that i am missing some values when i am iterating through the json object to place it in my javascript array. Here is what i mean  :

my rest api data:

```
    HTTP 200 OK
Allow: GET, HEAD, OPTIONS
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Accept

{
    "sales_rev_quota": [],
    "sales_revi": [
        {
            "month": 1,
            "sum": 123000
        },
        {
            "month": 2,
            "sum": 132000
        }
    ],
```

here is my code to extract it into a javascript array:

```
    endpoint = 'api/chart/data'
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: endpoint,    
  success: function(data){
    window.revi_sum = []
    window.revi_month = []


    window.sales_revi = data.sales_revi
    for(i=0 ; i < sales_revi.length  ; i++){
        revi_sum.push(sales_revi[i].sum)
        revi_month.push(moment().month(sales_revi[i].month - 1).format("MMMM"))
    console.log(revi_month)
    console.log(revi_sum)
    }
},
error: function(error_data){
console.log('error')
console.log(error_data)
}
})
```

this is what is shown in my console:

```
    ["January"]
0: "January"
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
(index):112 
[123000]
0: 123000
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logs are placed in the for loop body. Moving them beyond the for loop body should fix the issue.

```
window.sales_revi = data.sales_revi;

for (let i = 0; i < sales_revi.length; i++) {
  revi_sum.push(sales_revi[i].sum);
  revi_month.push(moment().month(sales_revi[i].month - 1).format('MMMM'));
}

console.log(revi_month);
console.log(revi_sum);
```

Comment: Hey there @mas thanks for replying , i realized it was within the for loop after awhile , however when i ammended it im getting a new error , it says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'sum' of undefined even though it was defined within the ajax call

Comment: @DionNeo hi, I think the code is fine, but the issue lays with ajax response's data. please add those logs right after the function's brackets, ``console.log(`Response: ${data}`);``, ``console.log(`sales_revi: ${data.sales_revi}`);``, run your test and get the output here.